# Issue with Angular Material date picker validation

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am validating a simple Angular Material date picker. It is weird because when I click on the little calendar it works fine but as soon as I click on the input field and before picking the date, the color becomes red as follows:

[image]

Here is the markup template:

```
    <mat-form-field class="datePicker">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()" readonly=true
            placeholder="Choose a date range" formControlName="dateRange">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And here is the typescript:

```
export class TrackingPanelComponent {


  toppingList: string[] = ['Machine A', 'Machine B', 'Machine C', 'Machine D'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  formGroup = this.fb.group({
    selectMachine: [null, Validators.required],
    dateRange: [null, Validators.required],
    trackingPath: [false],
    latestPosition: [false]
  })

  clearAll(){
    this.formGroup.reset()
  }
}
```

I know it is because of `(click)="picker.open()"` but I need to keep it to open the date picker easier. Any Idea to fix it?

Comment: First, is there any errors in the dev console? Second, looks like there's no default value even if it selects today as the date.

Comment: No error. If I add a default value, it works as expected. I need the date picker empty when the user opens the page.

Comment: Well the answer is there. It shows red because it doesn't have a valid date to use. What is the reasoning with not having a default? It will always pick today anyway, so you might as well set that date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that normally clicking on an input adds focus to it. However when calling the `picker.open()` method we lose focus immediately - which results in the validator registering a touch and therefore showing a validation error. Here's what I did

### 1 Disable default focus behaviour

We want to prevent the browser add focus on **mouseDown** (notice we bind to (mousedown) instead of (click) because that is where focus will happen by default)

```
(mousedown)="picker.open();$event.preventDefault()"
```

### 2 Validate form when datepicker closes

I did this by calling markAsTouched on formControl. **Note** - rather bind to method in the component.ts file.

```
<mat-datepicker #picker (closed) = "formGroup.get('dateRange').markAsTouched()"></mat-datepicker>
```

### Complete example

```
<mat-form-field class="datePicker">
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
       (mousedown)="picker.open(); $event.preventDefault" 
       readonly=true
       placeholder="Choose a date range" formControlName="dateRange">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker 
      (closed) = "formGroup.get('dateRange').markAsTouched()"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```